# How to get draggable element data when we drag and drop element from one array to another in VueDraggable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I am using VueDraggable and below is an array of phases, How can I get data(described below phases array) from events when we move a story from one phase to another.

```
const phases = [
  {
    pid: 'PH1',
    stories: [
      {
        sid: 'ST01',
        title: 'Story 1',
      },
      {
        sid: 'ST02',
        title: 'Story 2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    pid: 'PH2',
    stories: [
      {
        sid: 'ST11',
        title: 'Story 1',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Let say we are moving S01 from 0th index in phase (id: PH1) to 1st index in phase (id: PH2).
so tha I can get

- pid - from which element is moving (i.e PH1)
- index - index in an array from which it is moving(i.e 0)
- sid - the id of an element that is moving (i.e ST01)
- pid - to which element is moving (i.e PH2)
- index - index in array in which it is moving (i.e 1)

what I have tried

```
<draggable class="phase"
              group="containers"
              ghost-class="ghost"
              @end="checkEnd"
              v-model="phaseObj.stories"
              >
              <!-- :list="phaseObj.steps"> -->
      <!------------ STEP ---------------->
        <div v-for="step in phaseObj.stories"
              :key="step.stepId"/>
    </draggable>
```

**checkEnd** method

```
checkEnd(evt) {
      // HERE I AM GETTNG newDraggableIndex, newIndex, oldDraggableIndex, oldIndex
      // BUT I NEED PID AND SID ALSO
      console.log(evt);
},
```